# What are Vulkan's mesh shader outputs? Especially with regards to meshlets

Tags: graphics, glsl, vulkan

I think I will split this in to two questions, the first being more general, and the last being to do with my specific scenario.

I'm trying to convert my traditional rasterization pipeline in to a mesh shading pipeline, using meshlets.

#### Question 1

I see in examples the following things to do with the outputs of mesh shaders:

1. `SetMeshOutputsEXT(numVertices, numPrimatives)`
2. `gl_MeshVerticesEXT[idx] = ...`
3. `gl_PrimitiveTriangleIndicesEXT[idx] = ...`

Would I be correct in the following, and if not, I would welcome correction:

1. Defines the number of vertices and primitives this ***work group*** will be outputting.
2. Can be used to set attributes of the output vertices of this shader, such as `gl_Position`. `idx` must be between `0` and `numVertices`.
3. Can be used to define the primitive indices. For example, if `triangles` is used, one might write `gl_PrimitiveTriangleIndicesEXT[idx] = uvec3(a, b, c)` where `idx` is between `0` and `numPrimatives`, and `a`,`b` and `c` are indices between `0` and `numVertices`.

My guesses here are based off of [Niagara](https://github.com/zeux/niagara/blob/master/src/shaders/meshlet.mesh.glsl), [the `VK_EXT_mesh_shader` proposal](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Docs/blob/main/proposals/VK_EXT_mesh_shader.adoc) and [this article from Metal By Example](https://metalbyexample.com/mesh-shaders/).

#### Question 2

So for my specific use case, I have the following setup:

```c
layout(local_size_x = 64, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;
layout(triangles, max_vertices = 64, max_primitives = 64) out;

/* other stuff */

struct Meshlet
{
    uint vertex_offset;
    uint triangle_offset;
    uint vertex_count;
    uint triangle_count;
};

layout(binding = 4) readonly buffer Meshlets
{
    Meshlet data[];
} meshlets;

layout(binding = 5) readonly buffer MeshletVertics
{
    uint data[];
} meshletVertics;

layout(binding = 6) readonly buffer MeshletIndices
{
    uint data[];
} meshletIndices;

layout(binding = 7) readonly buffer Vertices
{
    Vertex data[];
} vertices;

/* other stuff */
```

This layout is meant to mimic that of my mental model and [Metal By Example](https://metalbyexample.com/mesh-shaders/)'s following image:
[image]

So:

1. `vertices` is the SSBO containing my mesh's full, raw, vertices.
2. `meshlets` is an SSBO of meshlet data.
3. `meshletsVertices` is an SSBO of indices in to `vertices`, ordered in groups of meshlet primatives.
4. `meshletsIndices` is an SSBO of indices in to `meshletsVertices`, ordered in groups of meshlet primatives.

Would I be correct in thinking these are what my outputs should be:

```c
void main()
{
    uint meshletIdx = gl_WorkGroupID.x; // One work group per meshlet
    uint meshletIndicesIdx = gl_LocalInvocationIndex; // Meshlet vertex between 0 and meshlet.vertex_count
    uint triangleNum = meshletIndicesIdx / 3;

    // Num meshlets in a mesh. This is meant so I can create multiple full meshes with a single call to vkCmdDrawMeshTasksEXT.
    const uint meshletsPerMesh = meshlets.data.length();

    Meshlet meshlet = meshlets.data[meshletIdx % meshletsPerMesh];

    SetMeshOutputsEXT(meshlet.vertex_count, meshlet.triangle_count); // 1

    if (meshletIndicesIdx < 3 * meshlet.triangle_count)
    {
        uint meshletVertexIdx = meshletIndices.data[meshlet.triangle_offset + meshletIndicesIdx];
        uint triIndex0 = meshletIndices.data[meshlet.triangle_offset + triangleNum * 3];
        uint triIndex1 = meshletIndices.data[meshlet.triangle_offset + triangleNum * 3 + 1];
        uint triIndex2 = meshletIndices.data[meshlet.triangle_offset + triangleNum * 3 + 2];

        if (meshletVertexIdx < meshlet.vertex_count)
        {
            uint vertexIdx = meshletVertics.data[meshlet.vertex_offset + meshletVertexIdx];
            Vertex vertex = vertices.data[vertexIdx];
            gl_MeshVerticesEXT[vertexIdx].gl_Position = vec4(vertex.inPosition, 1.0); // 2

            triIndex0 = meshletVertics.data[meshlet.vertex_offset + triIndex0];
            triIndex1 = meshletVertics.data[meshlet.vertex_offset + triIndex1];
            triIndex2 = meshletVertics.data[meshlet.vertex_offset + triIndex2];
            gl_PrimitiveTriangleIndicesEXT[triangleNum] = uvec3(triIndex0, triIndex1, triIndex2); // 3
        }
    }
}
```